# Extract tiff from WPS execute response

Tags: geoserver, xml, wps, 52north

I am very new with OWS, specially WPS, and I am testing 52North WPS for a project. I have run the Sextante visibility process, which result format is a tiff image.

The execute response starts as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:ExecuteResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsExecute_response.xsd"
    serviceInstance="http://localhost:8081/wps/WebProcessingService?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&amp;SERVICE=WPS"
    xml:lang="en-US" service="WPS" version="1.0.0">
    <ns:Process ns:processVersion="1.0.0">
        <ns1:Identifier xmlns:ns1="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">visibility</ns1:Identifier>
        <ns1:Title xmlns:ns1="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Visibilidad</ns1:Title>
    </ns:Process>
    <ns:Status creationTime="2013-04-17T12:13:16.298+02:00">
        <ns:ProcessSucceeded>Process successful</ns:ProcessSucceeded>
    </ns:Status>
    <ns:ProcessOutputs>
        <ns:Output>
            <ns1:Identifier xmlns:ns1="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">RESULT</ns1:Identifier>
            <ns1:Title xmlns:ns1="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Visibilidad</ns1:Title>
            <ns:Data>
                <ns:ComplexData mimeType="image/tiff"><![CDATA[MM?*?????????????????????
```

To extract the image to a file (to store it in Geoserver) I get the CDATA, decode with Base64Decoder to a byte array and the write it to a file, like visibility.tiff.

But this image seems to be "corrupted", I can't preview it and Geoserver fails when I try to create the datastore with the error: "Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: El argumento "value" no debe ser nulo." The last sentence means the argument "value" must not be null.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: check the python [OWSLib](http://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/#wps)

Comment: Thanks nickves. Do you know something similar in Java?